# SwiftUI ForEach loop not updating from ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, userdefaults

I started playing with SwiftUI in the last few days and it makes a lot of sense.
However, I'm struggling when it comes to updating a persisting list.

I'm using UserDefaults and JSONEncoder.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private var slackController = Slack()

    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.userData.statuses) { myStatus in
                    HStack {
                       // row code
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.slackController.setStatus(text: myStatus.description, emoji: myStatus.emoji)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
        }
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        self.userData.statuses.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
```

Both insert and delete are working, because when I relaunch the app I can see the changes.

```
private let defaultStatuses: [Status] = [
    Status(emoji: ":spiral_calendar_pad:", description: "In a meeting", expireHours: 1),
    Status(emoji: ":car:", description: "Commuting", expireHours: 12),
]

final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<UserData, Never>()

    @UserDefault(key: "ApiToken", defaultValue: "")
    var apiToken: String {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    @UserDefault(key: "Statuses", defaultValue: defaultStatuses)
    var statuses: [Status] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that `didChange.send(self)` is called, but I can't figure out why the list isn't updated.

The code is also in a [repo](http://github.com/hackzilla/slack-status-setter) in case I've missed something from the example that is useful.
I've also been using [SwiftUITodo](https://github.com/ivanvorobei/SwiftUI/tree/master/Other%20Projects/Example%20To-Do%20App/SwiftUITodo) to try figure out I'm doing wrong.

Any help/guideance would be appreciated.

Comment: There have been some changes to how Combine works. Look [here] (https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-changes-in-xcode-11-beta-5) to look at the changes.

Comment: I couldn't see anything more than a few variable name changes.  Also didSet to willSet.
It seems the issue might be that I'm using \@UserDefault and not \@Published, but I can't see how to combine them.

Comment: Actually, that seems to be all it was!  Thanks.

Comment: Glad that worked !